# Jetty creates a lot of temp folders for one app

Tags: java, grails, jetty, out-of-memory

I have a grails 2.3.11 web app deployed on jetty 8.1.11. When the service start, it created a lot temporary folders in the webapps folder (it goes up to 80000 folders now) and after a certain timed,i spot the following error in the log file :
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread` 
And the service begin to refuse connection. Do you have a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: 80,000 folders seems excessive, what do those folders look like? and where are they on your file system? (might give a hint on what is going on)

Comment: Btw, [Jetty 8 is EOL](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) (End of Life), consider upgrading.